# Android. Adjust resize not working on specific devices

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-softkeyboard, window-resize

I have an activity with `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`.
Everything works as expected for **adjustResize** mode. However, on some specific devices, after the keyboard is closed, there is an empty space on the screen from the keyboard. It looks like the screen couldn't be resize.

I found similar problems. But setting the **adjustPan** mode doesn't suit me.
I also tried to set the `fitsSystemWindows="true"` for my root view. It did not help.

My layout structure is:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        ....
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout>
```

For the Scroll View, I set the attribute `fillViewport="true"`

Please, help me)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following attribute values to your activity tag in **manifest**

```
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```